# DropdownSingleSelect user input type in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have claim 'country' with type 'DropdownSingleSelect' which has list of countries to be shown and 'SelectByDefault=true' enabled for 'US' country in list.

This control is shown to user in the 1st step of user journey and user changed the value in dropdown. Example, user selected 'UK'.

Now  in the 3rd step of user journey(self asserted), i have to show the same dropdown with the value he selected and get confirmation from user.

If i put that claim in outputclaim, dropdown is shown to user but default value 'US' selected. It should have shown the selected value as 'UK'.

If i remove 'SelectByDefault=true' attribute from list of values, it is showing as expected.

Is it expected behaviour or can it be fixed in user journey itself?

Comment: Hi @Raj. What happens if you add `<InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="country" />` to the self-asserted technical profile for the third orchestration step? This should pre-populate the drop-down value.

Comment: @ChrisPadgett I added this in tech profile of 3rd orch step. But it dropdown has default value selected('US'). It should have 'UK' which was selected by user in step1.

Answer (score 0):

I could address this by adding default value for the claim in the "sign up" technical profile (or any profile which shows the claim to user for the first time). This causes a default value to be selected in the dropdown. I have a countryCode claim with possible values as all countries. I haven't set SelectByDefault=true in ClaimType. I added following to sign up technical profile

```
<InputClaims>
  <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="countryCode" DefaultValue="IN"/>
</InputClaims>
```

Short version of the profile is

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail">
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="countryCode" DefaultValue="IN"/>
      </InputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="countryCode"/>
      </OutputClaims>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

At other places where the claim is used (and value is set), it automatically shows selected value.